# my flutter default splash screen is taking time to load

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

My flutter app's default splash screen takes too much time when the app opens time,

And also added the flutter `flavor's`

screen record is
[image]

My folder is

[image]

my `main_dev.dart` code is

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
  _initConfig();
  final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(
      (RemoteMessage message) => {print('onMessageOpenedApp $message')});
  var configuredApp = AppConfig(
    appDisplayName: "dev Config",
    fcmToken: fcmToken!,
    baseUrl: 'https://dev-services.ducoinsure.com/',
    appInternalId: 1,
    child: const MyHomepage(),
  );
  // HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  mainCommon();

  runApp(configuredApp);
}

Future<void> _initConfig() async {
  await _remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(RemoteConfigSettings(
    fetchTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    minimumFetchInterval: const Duration(seconds: 10),
  ));

  _fetchConfig();
}

void _fetchConfig() async {
  await _remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
}
```

my `InheritedWidget` is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppConfig extends InheritedWidget {
  const AppConfig(
      {super.key,
      required this.appDisplayName,
      required this.appInternalId,
      required Widget child,
      required this.baseUrl,
      required this.fcmToken})
      : super(child: child);

  final String appDisplayName, baseUrl, fcmToken;
  final int appInternalId;

  static AppConfig? of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<AppConfig>();
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => false;
}
```

Comment: Umm haven't you given it a minimum interval of 10 seconds? `minimumFetchInterval: const Duration(seconds: 10),`

Comment: in the debug mode its normal. Please check release build.

Comment: Both build's are take too much of time

Comment: Hi, @RisheekMittal  I don't know that bro. Which place to I add this line

Comment: In your `main_dev.dart` code inside the `Future<void> _initConfig()` function you can search for it by using Ctrl + F and then writing `_initConfig` in the window to find it

Comment: @RisheekMittal Already added this line bro...

Comment: I'm asking you to remove it or maybe change it to 2 or 3 seconds...